# Multi-row not working

Tags: tables, multirow

I am trying to use multirow to use to rows for a heading but for some reason, the line is still remaining in the middle. Here's my LaTeX table:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Manual vs old ICY}\\
\hline
\multirow{ 2}{*}{Model}&
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Senescent}&  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Young}\\ \hline
&Raw Count  &\%\ day3/day0 &Raw Count  &\%\ day3/day0\\ \hline
Manual vs old ICY&0.6482 &0.5074 &0.4397 &0.08118\\ \hline
Manual vs new ICY&0.6482 &0.5074 &0.4397 &0.08118\\ \hline
Manual vs VGG16&0.6482 &0.5074 &0.4397 &0.08118\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{ManualvsoldICY}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Replace the `\hline` with `\cline{2-5}`.

Comment: Many Thanks that worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` provides an easy way to draw such tables with merged cells and rules.

In `{NiceTabular}`, you use `\Block` to merge cells both horizontally and vertically and you use `hvlines` to draw all the expected rules (respecting the blocks).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccc}[hvlines]
\Block{1-5}{Manual vs old ICY}\\
\Block{2-1}{Model}&
\Block{1-2}{Senescent}&&  \Block{1-2}{Young}\\ 
&Raw Count  &\%\ day3/day0 &Raw Count  &\%\ day3/day0\\ 
Manual vs old ICY&0.6482 &0.5074 &0.4397 &0.08118\\ 
Manual vs new ICY&0.6482 &0.5074 &0.4397 &0.08118\\ 
Manual vs VGG16&0.6482 &0.5074 &0.4397 &0.08118\\ 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Ouput of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

Some off-topic improvement:

- instead `\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{...}` you should write `\multicolumn{2}{c|}{...}`
- labeling of table hasn't sense if table hasn't caption.

Considering aforementioned the MWE for your table is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{c|}{#2}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\caption{Manual vs old ICY}
\label{ManualvsoldICY}
    \centering
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
\multirow{2.4}{*}{Model}  &
    \mcc[2]{Senescent}  &  \mcc[2]{Young} \\ 
    \cline{2-5}
    & Raw Count & \% day3/day0  & Raw Count & \% day3/day0  \\ \hline
Manual vs old ICY
    & 0.6482    & 0.5074        & 0.4397    & 0.08118       \\ \hline
Manual vs new ICY
    & 0.6482    & 0.5074        & 0.4397    & 0.08118       \\ \hline
Manual vs VGG16
    & 0.6482    & 0.5074        & 0.4397    & 0.08118       \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]